# Resolving policy of Java constant pool

Tags: java, classloader, linkageerror

From many places like [Java SE Specifications](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-5.html#jvms-5.4.3.1) and "[Inside Java Virtual Machine](https://www.artima.com/insidejvm/blurb.html)", they all state the notion that when the resolution of a constant pool entry requires loading a type, the virtual machine uses the same class loader that loaded the referencing type to load the referenced type.

However, I find out this rule doesn't always hold:

```java
package com.alaneuler.test;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class LinkageMain {
    static class MyClassLoader extends ClassLoader {
        private Set<String> selfFirstClasses;
        private String name;

        public MyClassLoader(String name, ClassLoader parent, String... selfFirstNames) {
            super(parent);
            this.name = name;
            selfFirstClasses = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(selfFirstNames));
        }

        @Override
        public Class<?> loadClass(String name, boolean resolve) throws ClassNotFoundException {
            if (selfFirstClasses.contains(name)) {
                String filename = name.substring(name.lastIndexOf(".") + 1) + ".class";
                try (InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream(filename)) {
                    byte[] buf = new byte[is.available()];
                    int len = is.read(buf);
                    System.out.println(this.name + ": loading " + name);
                    return defineClass(name, buf, 0, len);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            if (!name.startsWith("java.")) {
                System.out.println(this.name + ": super.loadClass(" + name + ")");
            }
            return super.loadClass(name, resolve);
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return name;
        }
    }

    public static class User {}
    public static class Login {
        public void login(User u) {
            System.out.println("--- login called with user loaded by " + u.getClass().getClassLoader()  + " ---");
        }
    }
    public static class Main {
        public static void process() {
            User u = new User();
            new Login().login(u);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        MyClassLoader baseCL = new MyClassLoader("Base", LinkageMain.class.getClassLoader(),
                "com.alaneuler.test.LinkageMain$User",
                "com.alaneuler.test.LinkageMain$Login");
        MyClassLoader specialCL = new MyClassLoader("specialCL", baseCL,
                "com.alaneuler.test.LinkageMain$User",
                "com.alaneuler.test.LinkageMain$Main");

        specialCL.loadClass("com.alaneuler.test.LinkageMain$Main").getMethod("process").invoke(null);
    }
}
```

I define a customized `ClassLoader` which takes in its constructor a list of class names that should be defined by itself. Based on that, `baseCL` is configured to load class `Login` and `User` and `specialCl` to load `User` and `Main` (I know this setup breaks the class-loader delegation model).

Running this example produces:

```sh
specialCL: loading com.alaneuler.test.LinkageMain$Main
specialCL: loading com.alaneuler.test.LinkageMain$User
specialCL: super.loadClass(com.alaneuler.test.LinkageMain$Login)
Base: loading com.alaneuler.test.LinkageMain$Login
--- login called with user loaded by specialCL ---
```

which says `login` method is called with object `u` loaded by `specialCl` **not** `baseCL`. This phenomenon is contrary to the notion stated from the beginning, which is really weird and I cannot figure out where goes wrong.

Further, usage of `baseCl` to load class `User` always fails with `LinkageError`: `loader constraint violation: loader (instance of com/alaneuler/test/LinkageMain$MyClassLoader) previously initiated loading for a different type with name "com/alaneuler/test/LinkageMain$User"`.

My question is:

1. Shouldn't the invocation of `login` immediately raise an error?
2. Why the following usage of `baseCL` to load `User` fails with `LinkageError`?

Any help would be appreciated!

Credit given to Frank Kieviet's [blog](http://frankkieviet.blogspot.com/2009/03/javalanglinkageerror-loader-constraint.html) as the example is constructed from his delving of `LinkageError`.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: why `login` method is called with object `u` loaded by `specialCl` not `baseCL`, I think this invocation should raise error

Comment: The documentation states "To resolve an unresolved symbolic reference..." - `Main` is loaded by `specialCL`; it *uses* `User`, so `User` is also loaded by `specialCL` (as documented); no need for `baseCL` to load `User` (just my guess) {regarding "This phenomenon is contrary to the notion stated from the beginning, which is really weird and I cannot figure out where goes wrong"}

Answer (score 2):

Question 1: "Shouldn't the invocation of `login` immediately raise an error?"

No, because the resolution according to [Java SE Specification - Resolution](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-5.html#jvms-5.4.3) is done only when any of the instructions *anewarray*, *checkcast*, *getfield*, *getstatic*, *instanceof*, *invokedynamic*, *invokeinterface*, *invokespecial*, *invokestatic*, *invokevirtual*, *ldc*, *ldc_w*, *multianewarray*, *new*, *putfield*, and *putstatic* is executed.

- on the caller side (in `Main.process()`) the resolution is done and succeeds
- on the called side (in `Login.login()`) no resolution is done because you don't invoke any of the `User` class methods or access any of the fields of the class.
- the method call `u.getClass()` doesn't count because that resolves to the `Object.getClass()` method

---

Question 2: "Why the following usage of `baseCL` to load `User` fails with `LinkageError?`"

When the JVM loaded the `Login` class it already had a class named `User` available as loaded by the `specialCL`. It stored the pair (specialCL, "User") in the loader constraints for the `Login` class.

When the JVM now needs to resolve the `User` class within the `Login` class, it calls the `Login` classes classloader to load the `User` class. This loading however returns another `User` class instance (baseCL, "User") then the one that was recorded in the loader contraints (specialCL, "User").

For a description of the loading constraints see [Java SE Specification - Loading Constraints](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-5.html#jvms-5.3.4)